# Is it possible to have a textview slightly out of a cardview in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-cardview, android-relativelayout

Okay this may seem to be a easy question but trust me i have been spending hours to accomplished this. Just want to know whether it is possible to bring out a textview slightly of the right side of the cardView. Btw the texview is under many layouts such as linear layout and relative layouts.

I have tried adding this code in the xml of its parents layout as well. **android:clipToPadding="false"** and **android:clipChildren="false"** and it still doesnt work. Im not sure why it doesnt work for me. I have attached the image of how i want the layout of the textview to look like.Should i add some code in the adapter of my recyclerview? Please help. Thanks in advance

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:card_View="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_View:cardUseCompatPadding="false">



     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/random"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">




<TextView
        android:id="@+id/random2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



      <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/random3"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">



  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/random4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



  <View
        android:id="@+id/random5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>



<TextView
        android:id="@+id/this_is_the_textview_i_want_it_to_come_out_slightly"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>




        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**The code attached below is inside a cardView and the cardView will be placed in a recyclerview**

Comment: copy code here as text pls

Comment: @alirezadaryani i have added the code of the xml. Please help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving this effect. I'd do it by encapsulating the `CardView` inside another `ViewGroup` and then put the `TextView` (which should exceed the `CardView` bounds).

An example of one such layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"

        android:layout_margin="20dp"

        android:foreground="#ACDBDA"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="20% Off"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

        android:padding="7dp"

        android:elevation="5dp"

        android:background="@drawable/temp_rounded_border"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**temp_rounded_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#8080FF" />

    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        />

    <stroke android:color="#8080FF" android:width="1dp" />

</shape>
```

I haven't tested this code on a Device but here is what design view renders in Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: Hi @rana, welcome to StackOverflow, if you've found the answer helpful upvote it and since the answer solved your problem, I'd suggest you mark the answer as correct/accepted so that when someone else finds this post they know which answer has the best chance of solving their issue.

Answer (score 0):

try code below and update me in comments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/random"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/random2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/random3"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/random4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



            <View
                android:id="@+id/random5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"/>








        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/this_is_the_textview_i_want_it_to_come_out_slightly"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="what ever of your card view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="this_is_the_textview_i_want_it_to_come_out_slightly"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

if you want put anything anywhere use

> framelayout

as parent

Comment: if i place the textview like what u did, i wont achieve on the view i want. Did u see the image that i added, the view of what i want to achieve?

Comment: i have added the link of the image before the code.